Using IUnknown-derived interface in python / pywin32
In short: I'm trying to call a method on in IUknown-based interface. I have some parts, but they don't connect.
Situation:
o1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("SomeProgId")
o2 = o1.SubObject

The subobject is not co-creatable, o2._ole_obj_ is a <PyIDispatch at ...>`, as expected.
o2 also supports another interface, IMyInterface, derived form IUnknown, and I want to call a method on that interface.
The following:
iid = pywintypes.IID("{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}") // IMyInterface iid
o2._oleobj_.QueryInterface(iid)

fails with
TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID

The Queryinterface call itself succeeds (I've verified that in the source for the COM object), and if I specify an unsupported IID, the error message is different. The call fails even without trying to assing the result.

Okay, so I set out to find out about early binding support in python. Documentation seems spotty and outdated (or am I missing something?)
The following succeeds:
tlb = comtypes.client.GetModule(r"path-to-dll")
x = tlb.IMyInterface()

Of course x is not usable, but intellisense shows the correct methods etc. for x.
Generally, Intellisense shows all elements from the type library, so that part seems to work.
I've also tried:
myitf = win32com.client.CastTo(o2._oleobj_, 'IMyInterface')

which fails with

No module named 'win32com.gen_py.x0x2x4.IMyInterface'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "…\Python312-32\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client_init_.py", line 213, in CastTo
mod = gencache.GetModuleForCLSID(target_clsid)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
…
No module named 'win32com.gen_py.x0x2x4.IMyInterface'

2.4 is the typelib version, so everything looks good.
Any help?
